# must be vs. must have been

Tags: grammar

This paragraph is from a school textbook for high school students in Taiwan:

> When the gods and humans met Mecone to decide on the distribution of sacrifices that humans should make to the gods, Prometheus tricked Zeus for the benefit of humans. He slaughtered **a** bull and created two offerings. One was a pile of beef hidden inside **a** bull's stomach, and the other was a pile of bones covered in shiny fat. He then asked Zeus to choose one. The king of the gods chose the second one, believing there **must be** juicy meat underneath the fat,....

Is "must be" the correct usage here? Also, is it correct to use the indefinite article "a" for both sentences?

Comment: The background to this is that the greeks, when they sacrificed a bull, burnt the bones and fat as a offering to the gods, and then ate the rest.  This tries to justify this tradition of not sacrificing the meat, but only bones and fat.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to answer your questions.

"**must be**" is used correctly here.

"**a bull**" is also used correctly.

"**a bull's stomach**". You have not mentioned whether the text was "translated text" or "original English writing". You may not have that information. When such fables are found in English, majority of them are translated from Greek or Latin in one way or another. The translators may have done what was idiomatic of their times.

Complete details as to "whether stomach/s and/or fat from other bull/s are available" are unavailable. It is also not made clear how many stomachs a bull has or if that bull had more than one stomach.

Having done the preliminary work of explaining the ifs and buts of the hypothetical situation, here comes the interesting tidbit of how sentences are formed  or how sentences convey information. Sentence forming bases itself on common knowledge and common presumptions and assumptions.

Ordinarily we would think that "**a bull**" was slaughtered in the previous sentence, therefore the stomach(one stomach), fat, bones, beef came **from this bull**. In that sense "**a bull's stomach**" may be better used with the definite article, "**the bull's stomach**".

Comment: Thank you for replying so much! I did some research using what you said as a clue and was able to find that "must" was originally a past tense of the verb motan and is sometimes used in old-fashioned English and literary works. This piece of information is very helpful.

Comment: I was reminded of the fact that bulls do have more than one stomach as I read your reply. But I wonder whether the author really meant to go into such detail.  Also, as I first read the passage, the usage of the indefinite article in "a bull's stomach" made me pause and think whether Prometheus had used the stomach from a different bull. But I don't think that is the meaning. Thank you for pointing out that using the definitive article "the" may be a better choice.

Comment: You are welcome. I have corrected the spelling of definite (not definitive).